# Dart Set remove by index

Tags: dart

I try to figure out how can i remove from a set by using index. When i remove from the set, the set gets smaller. I get this error: `Uncaught Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 3: 3`

Somehow i need to figure out, if i want to remove `dog` i need to figure out the `newIndex` which is `2` due to first remove.

I know it's possible to do `animals.remove("objectName")` but in this case i want remove by index.

```
final Set<String> animals = {"lion", "tiger", "cat", "dog"};

void main() {
  int index = 1;
  animals.remove(animals.elementAt(index));
  int newIndex = 3;
  animals.remove(animals.elementAt(newIndex));
}
```

Comment: You should play with set elements using removeAll/removeWhere/retainAll.
Why do you absolutely use indexes?
If you want to stick with indexes removes you have to iterate over you set.

Comment: Why are you using a `Set` to begin with, when you want to work with indices? 
Sets don't generally promise to preserve order when you modify them (`LinkedHashSet` does, `HashSet` does not). They definitely do not preserve indices.

What you can do is that after you remove the `tiger` with index 1, you subtrace one from all indices greater than 1, so `int newIndex = 3 - 1 /* because index 1 was removed and 3 > 1 */;`. That way, if you cache indices, you can update the cached indices after each remove.

Answer (score 0):

Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range means that index 3 is more than the list length. Example:

```dart
final Set<String> animals = {"lion", "tiger", "cat", "dog"};

void main() {
  // Before removing the item your list has 4 items. All index: 0, 1, 2, 3
  int index = 1;
  animals.remove(animals.elementAt(index));
  // After removing an item from the list, the list has 3 items left. All index: 0, 1, 2
  int newIndex = 3; // <- As you can see above the 3 index does not exist in the list.
  animals.remove(animals.elementAt(newIndex)); // Uncaught Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range.
}
```

More safe method:

```dart
animals.removeWhere((animal) => animal.contains("tiger"));
```